# Link table values to ExtractByAttributes where_clause input

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, python

Using ArcGIS Desktop 10.7, I have 83 rasters that I need to loop through and perform an Extract By Attributes on using Python. Each raster has a range of values that the extracted pixels should be between. What I need to be able to do is insert the upper and lower bounding values from a table into the "where_clause".

ExtractByAttributes(in_raster, where_clause)

I'm not exactly sure how to link the appropriate values to the corresponding raster. Each raster is named after a "Map_ID" and the same "Map_ID" is located in the table. The table only has 3 columns, the Map_ID, upper and lower bounding values. The current python script I have is as follows (the 2 phrases "(Map_ID lower value)" and "(Map_ID upper value)" is what needs to call the values from a table):

```
# Import system modules
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *

# Set environment settings
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\data\Rast_conversion_Step_1"

# set output folder
outWorkspace = "C:\data\Rast_conversion_Step_2"

# create list of rasters to perform raster math on
RasterList = arcpy.ListRasters()

for item in RasterList:
      inSQLClause = "Value >= (Map_ID lower value) and Value <= (Map_ID upper value)"
      extractRast = ExtractByAttributes(item, inSQLClause)
      outputRaster = os.path.join(outWorkspace, item)
      ExtractByAttributes.save(outputRaster)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of looping through the rasters, use `arcpy.da.SearchCursor()` to loop through the table. Reference the raster with the `Map_ID` attribute, and build the where clause with the upper and lower bound attributes.

Comment: Thank you @Bjorn for the suggestion. Took a bit to figure out how to format a two part where clause so it wouldn't throw an error, but this approach definitely worked!

Answer (score 0):

I followed @Bjorn's suggestion of looping through the table instead of a list of rasters, and using the table ID to then select each raster for processing with the "ExtractByAttributes" function. This was a simple yet effective change in approach. For what it's worth this what I ended up doing. The two-part where clause made things a bit more complicated as I'm still pretty new to python and didn't know how to format that statement correctly. For clarity I split it into two parts and then combined them into one variable.

```
# Import system modules
import os
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *

Percentile_ranges = "C:\Data\All_data_10-40_percentile_ranges.csv"

output = "C:\Data\Focal_stats_output.gdb"

arcpy.TableToTable_conversion(Percentile_ranges, output, 'tempTable')
    
rast_loc = "C:\Data\Rast_conversion_Step_1"

# set output folder
outWorkspace = "C:\Data\Rast_conversion_Step_2"

fTable_1 = "tempTable"

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fTable_1, ["Field1", "Field2", "Field3"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        inRaster = os.path.join(rast_loc, row[0] + ".tif")
        whereclause_1 = """Value >= {}""".format(row[1])
        whereclause_2 = """and Value <= {}""".format(row[2])
        whereclause_3 = str(whereclause_1 + whereclause_2)
        extractRast = ExtractByAttributes(inRaster, whereclause_3) 
        outputRaster = os.path.join(outWorkspace, row[0]+".tif")
        extractRast.save(outputRaster)
```

Comment: `whereclause = """Value >= {} and Value <= {}""".format(row[1], row[2])` should work